# Markov Chain - Snakes and Ladders

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, conditional-probability

A simple game of snakes and ladders is played on a board of nine squares. At each turn a player tosses a fair coin and advances one or two places according to whether the coin lands heads or tails. If you land at the foot of a ladder you climb to the top, but if you land at the head of a snake you slide down the tail. how many turns on averages does it take to complete the game? What is the probability that a player who reaches the middle square will complete the game without slipping back to square 1?

This is a very famous Markov chain question. The original problem and the its image is here. it's the problem 1.3.3 in [Markov Chains](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521633966).

We can represent the chain with the following table
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \text{Start Square} & \text{If Head go to} & \text{If Tail Go to}  \\
1&2&5\\
2&5&4 \\
3&4&5\\
4&5&1\\
5&1&7\\
6&7&4\\
7&4&9\\
8&9&9\\
9&9&9
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are some general methods, but at that stage in the book I think you're supposed to work it out manually.

Let $p_i$ be the probability of reaching square nine before square one given that I'm on square $i$.

I need to come up with an equation involving $p_5$ that I can solve.
From square five I can reach only squares four five and seven before I reach square one or nine.

Looking at the table we may write
$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
p_4 &=& \tfrac 12 p_5 \\
p_5 &=& \tfrac 12 p_7 \\
p_7 &=& \tfrac 12 p_4 + \tfrac 12
\end{array}$$

It remains to solve this system of equations, which you shouldn't have much trouble with.

Comment: @ Tim: Thanks for your response. What I get stuck is the reasoning to derive the above Markov chain table. How did you figure that table? Again, thanks for your response

Comment: The table's very easy.  if there were no snakes or ladders the table would look very boring. All the rows would be in the form $n\quad n+1 \quad n+2$. because I can go forwards either one or two squares.  But I can't land on squares 3 6 or 8. There's a ladder on square three which takes me up to square 5 and there are snakes on squares 6 and 8.  So  I just changed every 3 to a 5, every 6 to a one and every 8 to a 4. To give me my table.

Comment: @ Tim: so average number of turns to complete the game is the expected value of all pi?

Comment: No, $p_n$ is a probability.  To get the average number of turns you would have to define  the average number of turns ($\mu_i$) before you finish if you start from square $i$. Then you get equations like $\mu_1 = 1+ \frac 12 \mu_2 +\frac 12 \mu_5$ from each line of the table.